# No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of()

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, android-studio

Okay so my code work (I have some things to fix but I can run It )but I have this error, I think the problem is on the main because  that's why the terminal say but I don't know how I can solve it.  If somoene can help me with that I will be very greateful as always ty

```
Future<void> main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();


 runApp(MyApp());
 }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return FutureBuilder(
  future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasError){
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(snapshot.error.toString(

          ),),
        ),
      );
    }
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
      return loading();
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      theme: myTheme.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: myTheme.darkTheme,

      home: SplashScreen(
      ),


}
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
      Navigator.of(context)
          .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Todolist(
      )));
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'stuffandmore/panda.png',
              height: 230,
```

Comment: Return the MaterialApp first always then in the `home` attribute provide a widget that will  do the `FutureBuilder` work. Your error happens because when snapshot is in error or waiting state there is no MaterialApp.

Comment: Ty really helpful